# How to determine number of months between two dates in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two columns that are datetime64[ns] objects. I am trying to determine the number of months between them.

The columns are:

```
city_clean['last_trip_date']
city_clean['signup_date']
```

Format is YYYY-MM-DD

I tried

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

city_clean['months_active'] = relativedelta(city_clean['signup_date'], city_clean['last_trip_date'])
```

And get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Does anyone know what could cause this issue? I feel like this is the most accurate way to calculate the number of months.

Answer (score 5):

This is Pandas, right? Try it like this:

```
# calculate the difference between two dates
df['diff_months'] = df['End_date'] - df['Start_date'] 
# converts the difference in terms of Months (timedelta64(1,’M’)-  capital M indicates Months)
df['diff_months']=df['diff_months']/np.timedelta64(1,'M')
```

Or, if you have proper datetimes objects,

```
def diff_month(d1, d2):
    return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind...

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> dt1 = datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=1)
>>> dt2 = datetime(year=2020, month=5, day=1)
>>> # delta = dt2-dt1
>>> delta = abs(dt2-dt1)

>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(61)

>>> delta.days
61
```

**UPDATE**:
What I meant to represent is the idea of using the absolute value of the delta -> abs()

In Python 3.10 it works with the `dateutil.realtivedelta()` too

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


city_clean_dates = [
    {'signup_date': '2019-12-01', 'last_trip_date': '2020-02-01'},
    {'signup_date': '2021-01-01', 'last_trip_date': '2020-05-01'},
    {'signup_date': '2020-03-01', 'last_trip_date': '2020-05-31'},
]

for city_clean in city_clean_dates:
    city_clean['last_trip_date'] = datetime.strptime(city_clean['last_trip_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    city_clean['signup_date'] = datetime.strptime(city_clean['signup_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')

    rd1 = abs(relativedelta(city_clean['last_trip_date'], city_clean['signup_date']))
    rd2 = abs(relativedelta(city_clean['signup_date'], city_clean['last_trip_date']))

    assert rd1 == rd2

    print(f"Recent - old date: {rd1}")
    print(f"Old - recent date: {rd2}")
```

this would print

```
Recent - old date: relativedelta(months=+2)
Old - recent date: relativedelta(months=+2)
Recent - old date: relativedelta(months=+8)
Old - recent date: relativedelta(months=+8)
Recent - old date: relativedelta(months=+2, days=+30)
Old - recent date: relativedelta(months=+2, days=+30)
```

Note neither of my solutions returns months, while the first one returns days only, and the second returns whole months + the extra days of the partial month.
The ambiguity of this is very obvious in the case of
`{'last_trip_date': '2020-03-01', 'signup_date': '2020-05-31'}`

Where normally we could say that's 3 months but in reality, it's one day short.
It's up to the developer to overcome the ambiguity of such values considering the use-case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the property you want from the `relativedelta`, in this case, `.months`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

rel = relativedelta(city_clean['signup_date'], city_clean['last_trip_date'])

city_clean['months_active'] = rel.years * 12 + rel.months
```